# Was Daniel's story of Nebuchadnezzar taken from Ludlul Bel Nemeqi?

Tags: daniel, source-criticism

The ***Ludlul Bel Nemeqi*** is often called the Babylonian Job due to it's similarities to Job however there are more similarities to the **Book of Daniel**, for instance,

The story is about a king who goes mad who was put out of his house and had to
wander outside like a recluse and an ox. He lost his position of authority and was replaced by someone else. He was like one who had gone crazy.

He was fettered. His fingernails grew out. He also has dreams that many fail to interpret. At the end of the story he is restored by God.

Here is the full text.: [Translation of *Ludlul Bel Nemeqi*](https://scholarlycommons.pacific.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1189&context=cop-facbooks).

The *Ludlul Bel Nemeqi* was written hundreds of years (It is thought to be written in 1200 B.C., Though I'm not sure what the oldest record we have of it is) before Daniel took place.

Comment: Who is supposed to have written the document ? Where was it discovered ? How is it being dated ? What language was it written in ? What other (authenticated) documents make definite reference to this document ? How were such authenticated documents dated ? Such detail and clarity is necessary if one is going to enter the arena of document dating and document authentication.

Comment: Tablet IV (page 10) footnote says: "The sources that comprise this Tablet are uncertain. In fact, the Tablet itself has only recently been suggested to exist within the poem."

Comment: To NigelJ : the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ludlul_b%C4%93l_n%C4%93meqi) on the poem answered your questions.  To @Lesley : please see my answer of a convincing explanation of the similarity of imagery between the poem and Daniel 4.

Answer (score 1):

To make the question more focused we can rephrase the question: **whether the author of the Biblical book of Daniel incorporated material from [*Ludlul bēl nēmeqi*](https://scholarlycommons.pacific.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1189&context=cop-facbooks), why, and how does it change the interpretation of Daniel?**  This is of course assuming that the Mesopotamian poem has been proven to be older than the earliest possible date of Daniel ([6th century BC](http://www.jesuswalk.com/daniel/app3_early-date-of-daniel.htm)), which is apparently the case, since scholars dated the poem to 13th century BC and we found a tablet dated around 7th century BC (see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ludlul_b%C4%93l_n%C4%93meqi)).

A *Journal of Biblical Literature* article from 2007, [*Chirps from the Dust: The Affliction of Nebuchadnezzar in Daniel 4:30 in Its Ancient near Eastern Context*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/27638436) by [Christopher B. Hays](https://www.fuller.edu/faculty/christopher-hays/), a professor of Ancient Near Eastern Studies, begins:

> This study begins with a simple question -- *Why is Nebuchadnezzar portrayed as an animal?* -- but it opens out onto an entire mythological motif and its tradition throughout the ancient Near East.  In short, the type of animal imagery found in this passage frequently symbolized those who were afflicted by divine powers.

After shortly summarizing two approaches -- 1) medical theory and 2) redaction critics theory (that identifies multiple sources and editors) Prof. Hays argued instead that

> ... Henze concludes (rightly, I think) that "it seems more plausible to turn ... to the Babylonian mythology in search of an explanation" for the imagery of 4:30.  ... With due respect to Henze's "inversion theory", better parallels to Dan 4:30 lie nearly as close at hand in Akkadian literature -- parallels that match rather than reverse the transformation, and that have comparable elements in divine agency.
>
> ...
>
> This article falls into two major sections.  The first demonstrates that the same complex of animal images that is found in Dan 4:30 was used to portray underworld figures (gods, demons, and the spirits of the dead) in Mesopotamia, in surrounding ancient Near Eastern cultures, and elsewhere in the Hebrew Bible.  In passing, this section also shows that drenching with rain is frequently employed as an image of supernatural affliction.  The second section shows the way in which imagery used to describe supernatural beings is transferred to those whom they afflict, specifically in prayer texts.  Prayers -- that is, thanksgivings and laments -- commonly link suffering to the encroachment of the powers of death.  Thus it is Nebuchadnezzar's *suffering* at the hand of God, rather than his madness, that this imagery should evoke.

and concludes:

> ... Daniel 4 uses imagery of the underworld to convey to the reader the extreme affliction of its main character: Nebuchadnezzar "ate grass like oxen, and his body was drenched with the dew of heaven, until his hair grew as long as that of eagles and his nails like those of birds." These descriptors, far from being naturalistic, are impressionistic, poetic evocations of long traditions of prayer.  Apart from these traditions, the animal imagery makes very little sense at all.
>
> ...
>
> This process can be seen both in Mesopotamian texts such as *Ludlul bel nemeqi* and in biblical texts such as the Psalms.  Although this adoption of underworld traits can be seen most clearly in poetic texts, even prose texts such as *Ahiqar* and Daniel 4 begin to co-opt the set of images for similar purposes: to express the depth of the suffering of the one telling the story.
>
> Daniel 4 makes this co-option clearer by adopting certain literary (esp. hymnic) features of prayers of thanksgiving. It might be said to play with and subvert that genre, just as it plays with and subverts the historical reality of the Babylonian empire.  While the portrait of Nebuchadnezzar may be strange to modern readers, the chapter's overall movement from affliction to salvation to thanksgiving would have been familiar to a people shaped by praying the psalms.  Surely many literate Jews in the Second Temple period would have understood Nebuchadnezzar's affliction in just this light.

#### Conclusion

Rather than seeing the story of Nebuchadnezzar as taken from *Ludlul bēl nēmeqi*, implying that the story in Daniel is *pious fiction*, it is more convincing to propose that the author of the book of Daniel adopted certain literary convention to portray in a literary manner understood by his original audience of how Nebuchadnezzar (a *real* historical person) has been afflicted by Israel's God (a *real* divine being) to show God's *real* power over the Babylonian empire.